# Angular, Chrome - all requests are stalled for about 450ms

Tags: angularjs, angular, google-chrome, http, httprequest

We have had a angularJS application, then we've updated our FE to angular7.1 and now every request in chrome is stalled for about 450ms, both static files and data requests.

**There isn't such an issue on local version of an application**

Firefox and IE don't block requests.

Do you have a any idea about this? Thanks.

Was tested with *Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate*

Was tested with only one request at a time

Was tested with and w/o proxy

(can't post images)

**Old app chrome behavior:**
[AngularJS behavior image](https://i.ibb.co/Kzfxnpp/stalled-request-old.png)

**New app chrome behavior:**
[Angular7 behavior image](https://i.ibb.co/qgpLWVR/stalled-request-new.png)

**New app IE behavior:**
[Angular7 IE behavior image](https://i.ibb.co/jJyHM4q/stalled-request-IE.png)

**UPDATE:**

Even first request is stalled.
Waterfall looks like this:
**[Waterfall](https://i.ibb.co/XXCJXnS/Angular7-waterfall.png)**

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/understanding-resource-timing

Answer (score 0):

Please read the following information in the [link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/understanding-resource-timing) that @JonathanHamel posted:

> A request being queued indicates that:
>
> - The request was postponed by the rendering engine because it's considered lower priority than critical resources (such as scripts/styles). This often happens with images.
> - The request was put on hold to wait for an unavailable TCP socket that's about to free up.
> - The request was put on hold because the browser only allows six TCP connections per origin on HTTP 1.
> - Time spent making disk cache entries (typically very quick.)
>
> Additionally, Stalled/Blocking is the time the request spent waiting before it could be sent. It can be waiting for any of the reasons described for Queueing. Additionally, this time is inclusive of any time spent in proxy negotiation.

Please tell us which of these case might apply to you.

Comment: I'm sorry for delay. 
[image](https://i.ibb.co/vqcPLsj/performance-tests.png)

I've figured out that the gap between "fetchStart" and "domainLookupStart" equals 'stalled time' displayed in timeline. According to article, this should be some kind of caching issue, but i can't find out which one. Request/Response headers are set to 
"Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate".